# Mobile first server 7.1 - Does MFP saves the Push Notification message?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

When push notifications are sent to MFP server from backend external server does MFP saves these messages and the status of delivery (Passed/Failed)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MFP cannot account for the success or failure of the message once it has passed to the vendor - APNS, GCM or MPNS. The messages are not stored, but may be queued until all are dispatched.